# Windows Explorer Repinning On Restart

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Every time I unpin windows explorer from my taskbar it comes back after I restart my computer. I have seen something that says go to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar and delete what I don't want but I don't have an AppData folder.

Comment: Is this a work computer? Certain policies can force icons to be pinned.

Comment: No, it is not a work computer.

Answer (score 0):

AppData folder is hidden by default. You can manually do the C:\Users\Username\AppData or make it visible under a checkbox on the top under "View".

Click "View" click "Hidden Items". This will show AppData.

Answer (score 0):

Click in the **Explorer** Address Bar & type: `shell:User Pinned` to navigate to the **User Pinned** folder. Then you double-click the **Taskbar** folder.